# Separate front-end and back-end service authentication in ASP. NET Core

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have created two separate projects for my web application:

- A Web API that implements the usual REST API, I call that the
  back-end
- A razor pages web app which is my front-end

(Basically followed what 
Jeffrey T. Fritz did in his [8 hour demo](https://github.com/csharpfritz/TripTracker) because it seemed like a well-separated architecture)
This means that both of there run server-side. I've added the "individual user" authentication option to my front-end which made a DB where the user data is stored and I can simply authorize pages based on the login there. To my understanding this auth. option basically means that the front-end manages it's own set of users in it's DB.

What I'm missing is protecting that Web API with that same authorization, so people wouldn't be able to anonymously use the API. How can that be done? Will the solution differ if I want to switch to Azure-based authentication?

I imagine the front-end would have to attach some user-related data to the requests and then the back-end would validate that somehow. (But I can't imagine how if it doesn't really know about the authentication service, maybe that has to be a separate entity accessible by both? In that case, should I just skip what I have and go straight to Azure?)

Note: I'm fairly new to security (and Web apps as a whole).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be worth taking a look at JWT Tokens for security. Its a pretty standard, well known pattern/method for securing web apps. Here is a more "full" description with example: https://garywoodfine.com/asp-net-core-2-2-jwt-authentication-tutorial/

You would be able to setup the security in one place, and use it to authenticate both applications

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction, I've read your link and I've read a bit more about JWT. Seems like it's pretty standard to do in Core and I'll be able to use this for AAD auth and such. Thank you!